# Trying to install python modules on cmd with windows 10 - Access is denied

Tags: cmd, pip, python-3.4, windows-10

I have been having trouble installing pip modules. I have python 3.4 and windows 10. When i type into cmd `python pip install [package]`, the computer comes up with an error saying "This app can't run on your pc" and cmd returns "Access is denied."

would this be a windows 10 incompatibility or is there something im missing/doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the command line as administrator?

Comment: Yes, I am running it as administrator

Comment: Have you set the environment variables?

Comment: Yeh, I put the directory to the python folder in PATH, however that did make me notice as cmd runs on C:\, and the directory that python is installed is on a larger hard drive H:\ would that make a difference?

Comment: Very well could do, the environment variables should be system wide though. Are you able to move the the pip modules/python onto the same drive and then run from that drive? cd / then (DRIVE): lets you change drive in cmd or maybe just the drive you want to access followed by a colon.